# How to scroll underneath a fixed background image

Tags: python, html, css

I am really new to html and css so excuse me if the questions sounds really basic.

What I am trying to achieve is I have a background image fixed at the top of the page. And I want everything to scroll underneath this bg image. The code for bg is

```
def set_png_as_page_bg(png_file):
    bin_str = get_base64_of_bin_file(png_file) 
    page_bg_img = '''
    <style>
    .stApp {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,%s");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    </style>
    ''' % bin_str
    
    st.markdown(page_bg_img, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    return
```

[image]

However, I want the text to scroll beneath the image. Is there a simple hack for that? I would also appreciate if someone can provide resource for this problem.

P:S: I also tried '''background-attachment: scroll''' but the bg does not scroll with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<style>
.stApp {
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,%s");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
```

And setting a height?

Comment: Okay. Do you want the image to be fixed or over the text? Need a bit more clarity then. Thanks

Comment: If there is a possibility to have both then yes both but otherwise I would like to have the image above the text.

Comment: You could try making use of the img tag to make things easier. Check out this link https://replit.com/join/rklysacvxx-jeffcorp